# Anyone else encountering "unknown error" when Initializing Cloud Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to launch an instance of Discourse on Google's Cloud Platform using their recently released "Launcher" (https://cloud.google.com/launcher/#/details/bitnami-launchpad:discourse?q=discourse)

It is able to create a new project, but during the step "Initializing Cloud Engine" it fails -- citing "Unknown error." as the reason.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Know how to get around it?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it - I am having the same problem

Comment: having the same error as well - has anyone been able to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Add billing information to account and your problem should be resolved.

Comment: Just checked, I already had billing information hooked up to my account.

Answer (score 1):

I had to generate an random project ID for the error to go away. Here's how that works.

Click the "Edit" button next to the project ID:

[image]

Generate a random project ID:

[image]

Create the project:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me while trying to create a project for the Google Coursera course.