# Creating project on Google Cloud Platform causes "Unknown error"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create my first project on Google Cloud Platform for my organization and get an '**Unknown error**'.

I have:

1. An active billing account.
2. A unique project name (actually tried many different names, see the screenshot).

[Screenshot of Google Cloud Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzSJZ.jpg)

Answers [Unknown error creating a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39923721/unknown-error-creating-a-project) and [Anyone else encountering "unknown error" when Initializing Cloud Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311203/anyone-else-encountering-unknown-error-when-initializing-cloud-engine) mention the same error, but but not helpful.

One specialty - my organization is a user of legacy Google Apps for Business. But this things shall not be related, right?

Answer (score 0):

The project could not be created because Google Developers Console App was disabled for the organisation.

**Solution**

1. Go to your G Suite console ([admin.google.com](https://admin.google.com)).
2. Search for "Google Developers Console" (Apps -> Additional Google services).
3. Right click on vertical dots (kebab menu) and set "ON for everyone".

Than you can go back to [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com) and create the project.